# Validation of viewstate MAC failed in IE. Works in Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, iis

Can't log in to intranet website from IE. From Chrome everything works fine. ASP.Net.Identity used to check if email is in DB. We don't use passwords, only corporate emails.
IIS used to host web-site.

```
Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055 for more information. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055 for more information.

Source Error: 


 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 



[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
    Client IP: 10.9.67.57
    Port: 53656
    Referer: http://idt_val_vm_srv/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FEnterHours%2F%3Fdate%3D2018-05-01
    Path: /Account/Login
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
    ViewState: NLiXWsLtnB/N9glviq6iJpahHR6xrvla7oVYkgXEW5YLbmw0ybMslZZmm3wm8hEhTtfD6CoQGX6STbZ0ZqSrjGSjBZIg+CbZ7yT+zbC2WntSQp4BBFYRnkV0kvIEs9ITyI4bTXQHu5hwYXEmgT7pe9gSxy1VYXtpkt7C50bx5NI4Ka/Tj1oFvjV2cllBDYE0n3HEUo7x003pbI7yQllr3A==]

[HttpException (0x80004005): Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055 for more information.]
   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) +153
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString, Purpose purpose) +912
   System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter2 formatter, String serializedState, Purpose purpose) +61
   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +309
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() +367
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +46
   System.Web.UI.<ProcessRequestMainAsync>d__523.MoveNext() +13873
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
   System.Web.Util.WithinCancellableCallbackTaskAwaiter.GetResult() +32
   System.Web.UI.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__515.MoveNext() +790
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
   System.Web.UI.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__554.MoveNext() +616
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
   System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar) +64
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +607
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +134
```

Comment: It is a single Windows server. I already tried <pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode ="Never"> in web.config and it doesn't work

Comment: If I deploy on another server, login works fine.

Comment: Actually all pages have this error after postback.

Comment: And I tried generating machine keys and putting it to web.config

Comment: This is one of the logs: